# New Roof Looks Like It Has Damage Already

Tags: roofing

So I had a new rood put on and I had all these marks on the new rood where to me it looks like granules are missing and a shingle they used was torn and glued down. I just want to make sure im not being too picky or if it really is sub par work.

They have came out two additional times to replace shingles but there is still these marks. Today after they left there is not roofing caulk over some spots that I am not sure why they are there.

Here are the photos: https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipPPD7eyWtLLcGYGX_T3H55ZWc_kcByhyJKZO_F4Wc5N2u0yc3g_9rPyz-eZ8dzZ2g?key=UVdCZlVGX3lwaVNRWmFNRmNuUlJDek1KWDFuMHZn

An example of the roofing caulk spots is:
https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipPPD7eyWtLLcGYGX_T3H55ZWc_kcByhyJKZO_F4Wc5N2u0yc3g_9rPyz-eZ8dzZ2g/photo/AF1QipN_jvPGgjM6dvMcUvReiIJq5we3Z19KvpsmAse5?key=UVdCZlVGX3lwaVNRWmFNRmNuUlJDek1KWDFuMHZn

An example of the  missing granules:
https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipPPD7eyWtLLcGYGX_T3H55ZWc_kcByhyJKZO_F4Wc5N2u0yc3g_9rPyz-eZ8dzZ2g/photo/AF1QipNJ0jyCb7wY8ci7mAR7HVJPOW-GXiuryyLNj3d3?key=UVdCZlVGX3lwaVNRWmFNRmNuUlJDek1KWDFuMHZn

The question is are these normal items for having a roof done or should it all look brand new? This is just the roof on my porch I have not even looked at my tall part of the roof due to the height.

Thank you

Comment: the 3 shiners that were covered in tar or blackjack (this is normal in cases where a shiner was needed) I did not see anything bad 10 photos of the tar paper / felt should have not been there this suggests you are being two picky. the 1 point that had some tar/gravel was not very clear. What I saw was a industry normal roof job. a better evaluation put 1,2or 3 photos crisp and clear and eliminate the tarpaper photos that can be put up really bad (Not straight or parallel) and not make a difference as long as the shingles run true. You will need to clean out the gravel in the gutters in spring

Comment: Hey Ed, Thank you for the reply. Not all the photos were problems, just photos of the whole roof job in the album. The main issues were the examples of the shiners as you call them and drag marks on the roof like referenced above or https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipPPD7eyWtLLcGYGX_T3H55ZWc_kcByhyJKZO_F4Wc5N2u0yc3g_9rPyz-eZ8dzZ2g/photo/AF1QipMkw22B3w8uLRIGKvpDZPWl4rgDSGr4Ogrq1hCd?key=UVdCZlVGX3lwaVNRWmFNRmNuUlJDek1KWDFuMHZn which has a lot of marks on the roof. Thanks for the tip on cleaning out the gravel.